# Viewing MariaDB column_list result via DBForge

Tags: mysql, resultset, mariadb, heidisql, dbforge

Using the example in provided by DBForge for [COLUMN_LIST](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/fusion/docs/index.html?dynamic_columns_functions.htm) against the table assets, when I run the following:

```
SELECT item_name, column_list(dynamic_cols) FROM assets;
```

Through DBForge Studio, the resultset for `column_list(dynamic_cols)` is shown as an image / icon when viewed in Grid mode while it displays `long" in Text mode.

However running the same query with HeidiSQL, I can see the actual comma separated result set for `column_list(dynamic_cols)`.

Is there a result why DBForge Studio doesn't display the comma separated result set? is there a setting I have to change or click in order to view it?

Answer (score 0):

The actual version of dbForge Studio for MySQL does not produce such errors. The only exception is the case of having more than 2000 characters in a “cell”. In that case, the data is presented as a symbol – from the 2001st character and further.

[image]

It relates to all data types and is caused by optimization. Concerning your data type, Dynamic Columns are used when the number of possible attributes is too high. For instance:

Max number of columns   65535

Max total length of packed dynamic column   max_allowed_packet (1G)

Therefore, such optimization is necessary for the Studio to work appropriately.